# make a sub-list from a list which has minimum positive difference between its minimum and maximum elements

Tags: python, arrays, list, min, difference

how can a list of ,say, 4 elements can be made from a list of 6 or 7 elements based on the condition that the positive difference between the minimum and maximum elements of the new list will be minimum?

we know that the minimum difference between two array elements can be found. But how can a sub-list can be made based on it that will have less elements than that of the main bigger list ??

Comment: Is it a list of numeric values? Can you give an example of what the expected output should be?

Comment: Sort the original list, make slices of length `n` then find the min slice such that the `[0]` element of that slice is closest to the `[n-1]` element of that slice

Answer (score 0):

If you have a new list of 2 elements that fulfill this condition, then adding as many other elements as you like won't change the situation. So all you need to do, is to find the two elements of the original list that are closest together. From there you can expand to any other list.

So you could sort the list and check differences of subsequent elements:

```py
original = [1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 15, 17]
s_orig = sorted(original)
pairs = list(zip(s_orig, s_orig[1:]))
closest = min(pairs, key=lambda x: x[1] - x[0])
new = list(closest)  # ... optionally add any other elements from 'original' as well
```